# Compressing CSS YUI compressor

Tags: css, compression

Anyone know which option is needed to compress all css in one line. I am using a wordpress plugin called bwp-minify, however the plugin's css level of compression is low and i am trying to change it through the YUICompressor.php

I tried changing line-break to 0 and to 100000 but none have effect.

Is it the following;

```
  --line-break
      Some source control tools don't like files containing lines longer than,
      say 8000 characters. The linebreak option is used in that case to split
      long lines after a specific column. It can also be used to make the code
      more readable, easier to debug (especially with the MS Script Debugger)
      Specify 0 to get a line break after each semi-colon in JavaScript, and
      after each rule in CSS.
```

Source Code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Class Minify_YUICompressor 
 * @package Minify
 */

/**
 * Compress Javascript/CSS using the YUI Compressor
 * 
 * You must set $jarFile and $tempDir before calling the minify functions.
 * Also, depending on your shell's environment, you may need to specify
 * the full path to java in $javaExecutable or use putenv() to setup the
 * Java environment.
 * 
 * <code>
 * Minify_YUICompressor::$jarFile = '/path/to/yuicompressor-2.3.5.jar';
 * Minify_YUICompressor::$tempDir = '/tmp';
 * $code = Minify_YUICompressor::minifyJs(
 *   $code
 *   ,array('nomunge' => true, 'line-break' => 1000)
 * );
 * </code>
 * 
 * @todo unit tests, $options docs
 * 
 * @package Minify
 * @author Stephen Clay <steve@mrclay.org>
 */
class Minify_YUICompressor {

    /**
     * Filepath of the YUI Compressor jar file. This must be set before
     * calling minifyJs() or minifyCss().
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public static $jarFile = null;

    /**
     * Writable temp directory. This must be set before calling minifyJs()
     * or minifyCss().
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public static $tempDir = null;

    /**
     * Filepath of "java" executable (may be needed if not in shell's PATH)
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public static $javaExecutable = 'java';

    /**
     * Minify a Javascript string
     * 
     * @param string $js
     * 
     * @param array $options (verbose is ignored)
     * 
     * @see http://www.julienlecomte.net/yuicompressor/README
     * 
     * @return string 
     */
    public static function minifyJs($js, $options = array())
    {
        return self::_minify('js', $js, $options);
    }

    /**
     * Minify a CSS string
     * 
     * @param string $css
     * 
     * @param array $options (verbose is ignored)
     * 
     * @see http://www.julienlecomte.net/yuicompressor/README
     * 
     * @return string 
     */
    public static function minifyCss($css, $options = array())
    {
        return self::_minify('css', $css, $options);
    }

    private static function _minify($type, $content, $options)
    {
        self::_prepare();
        if (! ($tmpFile = tempnam(self::$tempDir, 'yuic_'))) {
            throw new Exception('Minify_YUICompressor : could not create temp file.');
        }
        file_put_contents($tmpFile, $content);
        exec(self::_getCmd($options, $type, $tmpFile), $output);
        unlink($tmpFile);
        return implode("\n", $output);
    }

    private static function _getCmd($userOptions, $type, $tmpFile)
    {
        $o = array_merge(
            array(
                'charset' => ''
                ,'line-break' => 5000
                ,'type' => $type
                ,'nomunge' => false
                ,'preserve-semi' => false
                ,'disable-optimizations' => false
            )
            ,$userOptions
        );
        $cmd = self::$javaExecutable . ' -jar ' . escapeshellarg(self::$jarFile)
             . " --type {$type}"
             . (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+$/', $o['charset'])
                ? " --charset {$o['charset']}" 
                : '')
             . (is_numeric($o['line-break']) && $o['line-break'] >= 0
                ? ' --line-break ' . (int)$o['line-break']
                : '');
        if ($type === 'js') {
            foreach (array('nomunge', 'preserve-semi', 'disable-optimizations') as $opt) {
                $cmd .= $o[$opt] 
                    ? " --{$opt}"
                    : '';
            }
        }
        return $cmd . ' ' . escapeshellarg($tmpFile);
    }

    private static function _prepare()
    {
        if (! is_file(self::$jarFile)) {
            throw new Exception('Minify_YUICompressor : $jarFile('.self::$jarFile.') is not a valid file.');
        }
        if (! is_dir(self::$tempDir)) {
            throw new Exception('Minify_YUICompressor : $tempDir('.self::$tempDir.') is not a valid direcotry.');
        }
        if (! is_writable(self::$tempDir)) {
            throw new Exception('Minify_YUICompressor : $tempDir('.self::$tempDir.') is not writable.');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **not** using the --line-break option?

When I use YUI compressor I don't specify that option and the output is on a single line.

---

Judging from the source code you provided wherever you call

```
Minify_YUICompressor::minifyCss('/path/to.css');
```

You need to set the `line-break` option to `-1` like this:

```
Minify_YUICompressor::minifyCss('/path/to.css', array('line-break' => -1));
```

Comment: I commented out but it didnt work, the output is as following... [link](http://n1bar.com/wp-content/plugins/bwp-minify/min/?f=wp-content/plugins/usernoise/css/button.css,wp-content/plugins/dpSocialBar/css/dpSocialBar.css,wp-content/plugins/special-recent-posts-2.4.7/css/css-front.css,wp-content/plugins/ubermenu/styles/basic.css,wp-content/plugins/ubermenu/styles/skins/blacksilver.css&amp;ver=1342096143)

Comment: I downloaded it and compressed it myself without --line-break and got everything on 1 line.  Can you link me to the YUICompressor.php you're using.

Comment: No, I mean the place you downloaded YUICompressor.php from.

Comment: I've tried all of them nothing seems to work, im gona try and contact again the plugin developer. :( thanks alot anyways for your time m8 cheers

Comment: Its not really what I would normally recommend but...

You could also comment out the code that adds the `--line-break` option to the command like so : http://codepad.org/NYjetsVK

Answer (score 0):

put the following code at the beginning of you php script

```
<?php header('Content-Type:application/javascript'); ?>
```